# JQuery Mobile 1.1.1 Nested List not scrolling properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, nested-lists

i am buildung some nested lists dynamically. To help you understand how exactly here is a little abstracted example.

To add a subcategory i do:

```
obj.append('<ul id="' + id_ul + '"></ul>');
$("#" + id_ul).append('<li id="' + id + '"><h3>' + name + '</h3><p>' + text + '</p></li>');
$("#" + id_ul).append('<li id="' + id2 + '"><h3>' + name2 + '</h3><p>' + text2 + '</p></li>');
```

And to add an item in one of those categories i do:

```
obj.append('<ul id="' + id_ul + '"></ul>');
$("#" + id_ul).append('<li id="' + id + '" data-icon="false"><a id="' + ida + '" href="#"><h3>' + name + '</h3><p>' + text + '</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + info + '</strong></p></a></li>');
$("#" + id_ul).append('<li id="' + id2 + '" data-icon="false"><a id="' + ida2 + '" href="#"><h3>' + name2 + '</h3><p>' + text2 + '</p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>' + info2 + '</strong></p></a></li>');
```

obj is of course always the parent object i want the new subcategory or item to be attached to. So i do it all by appending to an id.

I used this code with Version 1.0.1 an it worked fine and now i switched to 1.1.1 (an also have the samme issue with 1.2.0 alpha) and this is my problem:

- page with only categories in the nested list: works fine
- page with only items in the nested list: works fine
- page with both, categories and items in the nested list: **If the list extends the screen height it is not scrollable and after one of those not scrollable pages was displayed all other pages within my navigation also are not scrollable anymore until i do reload the whole page**

Is there any know issue with nested listviews and scrolling from JQueryMobile 1.1.1 up? Or am i buildng the list wrong?

This is driving me crazy at the moment so any idea is highly appreciated!

EDIT:

This is a sample HTML of the final list with a subcat and 2 items in it:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="mylist&amp;ui-page=ul_4" data-theme="c" data-count-theme="c" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="c" class="ui-header ui-bar-c" role="banner">
        <div class="ui-title">myuppercat</div>
</div>

<div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main">
    <ul id="ul_4" class="ui-listview">
        <li id="li_2134" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-btn-up-c">
            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                    <a href="#mylist&amp;ui-page=ul_4" class="ui-link-inherit"><h3 class="ui-li-heading">mysubcat</h3><p class="ui-li-desc"></p></a>
                </div>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="li_2136" data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-c">
            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                    <a id="2136" href="#" onclick="javascript:dosomething(this)" class="ui-link-inherit"><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong>somedetail</strong></p><h3 class="ui-li-heading">item1</h3><p class="ui-li-desc"></p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="li_2137" data-icon="false" data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-c">
            <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-text">
                    <a id="2137" href="#" onclick="javascript:dosomething(this)" class="ui-link-inherit"><p class="ui-li-aside ui-li-desc"><strong>somedetail</strong></p><h3 class="ui-li-heading">item2</h3><p class="ui-li-desc"></p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example of the html that is created when it's not working properly?

Comment: Added html example from a run with 1.1.1

Comment: The html looks ok (noting `id`s starting with numbers are html5 only). I can only suggest analyzing the diff between the CSS of 1.0.1 and 1.1.1, or redesigning your list structure, perhaps using nested `ul`s, which is the usual way of displaying nested lists.